# Looping within existing loop on object

Tags: javascript

I'm currently looping on an object in javascript and successfully got what I need from the `_source` level. My problem now is that there is another array under `color` inside `_source`.

Currently, `console.log(searchResult);` gives me this object:

```
1
  _source
    color
      1
        color_type
    type
      name
        id
```

I can access `type` and `color` because they're on the `_source` level, but I need to access `color_type` which is part of another array within `color` and it needs to obviously be the info contained in my originally indexed element.

Do I need to create a new loop here to access the `color` info?

```
    let searchResult = response.hits.hits;
    console.log(searchResult);
    for(let i = 0; i < searchResult.length; i++) {           

                //This line displays the name.id properly
                document.getElementById("name").value = searchResult[i]._source.type.name.id;   

                //this line gives undefined         
                document.getElementById("color").value = searchResult[i]._source.color[i].color_type;
        })  
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share your object with us?

Comment: Basically yes because `_source.color` is an array that can contain multiple elements, but ultimately it depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you only ever interested in the first colour, where present?

Comment: Yes, in this case only the first @Rup

Comment: Is `1` the only index inside `color`?

Comment: @ChukwuemekaInya for now it is, but even if there are more I'm concerned only about the first one

Comment: Tom, are you interested in index 1 of color array or the first element in color array?

Comment: @SujilMaharjan always first element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are only interested in the second element (index 1), this should do the trick:

```
document.getElementById("color").value = searchResult[i]._source.color[1].color_type;
```

Comment: So, this is weird but it does apply the proper value however it says 'cannot read property 1 of undefined?

Comment: Tom, first element in an array starts with index 0 and not 1. :)

Comment: Please look at my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Since color is also an array and you are trying color[i], it is looking for multiple indexes in color array through the index of searchResult array.

If you are only interested in the first element of color array, you should do this:

`document.getElementById("color").value = searchResult[i]._source.color[0].color_type;`

Instead of assigning `i`, you assign `0` to get the first color only.

If you are looking for multiple colors, you need to create a separate loop that only loops from `color[0]` to `color[color.length]`

Answer (score 1):

If you're **sure** the key in the color will **always be 1**, just use:

```
document.getElementById("color").value = searchResult[i]._source.color[1].color_type;
```

If you're **not sure**, use:

```
for (let i = 0; i < searchResult.length; i++) {           

    document.getElementById("name").value = searchResult[i]._source.type.name.id;   

    for (let j = 0; j < searchResult[i]._source.color.length; j++) { 

        // this set to the #color element the first not undefined color_type from color array
        if (searchResult[i]._source.color[j].color_type != undefined) {

            document.getElementById("color").value = searchResult[i]._source.color[j].color_type;
            break;

        }         

    } 

}
```